# How to make these rounded corners in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4jGy.png)
How can i add border-radius to the corners? (Must see the image). 
The Image on the right is the target image, mine is the one on the left. 
Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="midsquare"> </div>
<div class="square1"> </div>
<div class="square2"> </div>
<style> 
  body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #F3AC3C;
  }  
 .midsquare {
   position: absolute;
    width: 70;
    height: 70;
    background: #F3AC3C;
   border-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 1
  }  
  .square1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65;
    left:65 ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 150;
    height: 100;
    background: #1A4341;
  }  
    .square2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65;
    left:65 ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 150;
    height: 100;
    background: #1A4341;
      transform: translate(80%,70%)
  }   
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: It showed only orange background in your code

Comment: Please check your snippet. The elements aren’t positioned or sized correctly, no units. But having said that, are you needing these to be separate elements or do they just form a background?

Comment: @AHaworth I need them to be separated elements.